# What are the consequences of a feature-gated enum variant?

Tags: rust, enums, conditional-compilation

What if a library crate defines an `enum` that has a variant that is feature-gated?

```rust
#[non_exhaustive]
enum Foo {
    A,
    B,
    #[cfg(feature = "some-feature")]
    Gated,
}
```

This is a naïve attempt to allow the `enum Foo` to support the optional feature with the `Gated` variant, while also allowing clients who do not need the feature to opt out of the costs associated with it (by disabling the crate feature `some-feature`).

What are the potential dangers and/or costs associated with doing this? Are there any compelling reasons for avoiding this pattern?

Comment: As a side note, I'm not sure how I feel about `#[non_exhaustive]` on enums. I think in some cases it can make sense where you rarely want to match all the possible variants (think keyboard scancodes in a GUI application) but in others, I think it actually causes more problems than it solves. It forces a `_` arm whenever enum values are matched, which in many cases will just panic. This means that introducing a new enum variant creates a runtime error instead of a compile-time error which is the _exact opposite_ of what I would usually want.

Comment: That said, I am going to vote to close this as opinion-based. _My_ opinion is that there is nothing wrong with cfg-gated enum variants, but I would remove `#[non_exhaustive]`. If another variant springs into existence due to features being changed, I would _want_ the compiler to tell me all of the places in my codebase that I need to look at to consider the new variant.

Comment: Posted the slightly modified question on URLO - https://users.rust-lang.org/t/a-possible-edge-case-for-semver/90117. In short, the answer on that (modified) question is "without `#[non_exhaustive]`, this is explicitly disallowed by Cargo conventions".

Comment: @cdhowie I believe that if a feature-gated enum variant exists, the enum should always be marked with `#[non_exhaustive]` because "Enabling a feature should never introduce a semver incompatible change"

Comment: @RBF06 That's super unfortunate. It removes one of the primary advantages of compile-time exhaustive match checking.

Answer (score 5):

If the enum is *not* marked with `#[non_exhaustive]`, this may lead to an unexpected and effectively unsolvable breakage on the binary crate's side.

Imagine the following case:

- Your library `foo` exports this enum:

```
pub enum Foo {
    A,
    B,
    #[cfg(feature = "some-feature")]
    Gated,
}
```

- Library `bar` depends on `foo` *without* feature and matches on `foo::Foo`, handling `Foo::A` and `Foo::B` and ignoring `Foo::Gated`, since it doesn't exist in this confiuguration.
- Binary `baz` depends both on `bar` and on `foo`, *with* feature.

Then, `bar` by itself works fine, but attempt to build `baz` will fail, since features will be unified across dependency tree, and when `some-feature` is active, `bar` breaks.

Comment: I see. Are there any dangers or reasons for avoiding this pattern even when the enum is marked with `#[non_exhaustive]`?

Comment: For me, is would just look very surprising (that is, I'd question why it was ever needed if found this in the wild). But probably not dangerous.